# correct ways of using windows service?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, standards

I have a WPF application with a own windows service as helper. I'm planning to push some of the background tasks (fetching data from internet, sending emails etc.) to the windows service, so that the service will carry it out independent of the app (even if app is closed).

I've been searching for the correct / efficient way of doing it. I read about timers to trigger after some span and check for task. Also, trigger an event on the service and carry out the task.

I'm confused what way would be appropriate and widely used. Any convention? Any standard way of doing this?

Comment: Both of your described scenarios are possible. Your service could periodically perform some tasks based on a timer. E.g. it could fetch the data every hour. You could then additionally use this windows service to host an wcf service, so that your client application could trigger that fetching task via an exposed web service method.

Comment: I had a small error in my first comment; what I meant to say was that if it is your own service, your own work you could implement communication via standard output. Because in that scenario you would have full control of the flow of each of the 2 applications.

Comment: Inter-process communication has many approaches. If your Windows service is also written in .NET you can use self hosted WCF or Web API.